# Using a bigger grid (>940px) with Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Has anyone worked with the Bootstrap grid system using a content area >940px (currently defined width of the 12 column grid)?

I'd like to use the Bootstrap pattern for divs (container > rows > col-xx-x) but on a wider grid (like 1200px or something).

Comment: Yeah I worked on bigger screen ... so what's you question?

Comment: The largest grid option for bootstrap is for widths of 1200px or larger, sooooo I'm not sure what you're asking. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Comment: The answer you seek is : Yes.

Comment: My understanding is that the Bootstrap grid only has an effective canvas of 940px. Trying to figure out the best way to approach columns that have a larger width (e.g. less margin on the left/right side of the screen). From the sounds of it, I'm going to have to do some of my own math here.

Comment: It's all just a matter of adjusting the variable values for grid gutter, padding, etc. Plus, `.container-fluid` is completely fluid, expands to arbitrarily wide screen size.

Comment: @cvrebert Thanks. I wasn't aware that I could adjust those params. Found em via http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#container-sizes. Will see if I can tweak it to what I was looking to do in the next few days.